# where can I set the axis for the simple deform modifier ?

Tags: modeling

The title should say it all, I want to use a twist but there is not option for the axis. Why is that and how do we get around this ?

Answer (score 5):

You can add an empty and chose it as origin object in the modifier on the deformed object.

[image]

By rotating the empty you can change the direction of the deformation.

Comment: It should probably be mentioned that the local Z-Axis of the origin object is the one that is used in the deformations. That stumped me for a while.